# Tooltip on Button

Tags: wpf, xaml, wpf-controls

I am trying to set tooltip on button as shown in the code below based on image choice. I want to set tooltip based on Image if button displays normal image I would like to set tool tip as "Active" and if displays mouse hover image then tool tip should be "Non-Active". I can set tool tip on main button without any problems. Images displays fine,however I am not able to toggle/display tooltip based on normal or hover image.

```
NormalHoverImageButton
```

is standard button that contains two DependencyProperties that hold the normal image and the hover image as ImageSource. Is there any way in the xaml, I can set this tooltip property.

```
   <c:NormalHoverImageButton DockPanel.Dock="Left" 

   ToolTip="Display Tool Tip"                                                             
    NormalImage="{Binding Status, Converter={StaticResource NormalImageSourceConverter}}" 
    HoverImage="{StaticResource MouseHoverImage}" 
    Visibility="{Binding IsTestTrue, Converter={StaticResource MyVisibilityConverter}}">

  </c:NormalHoverImageButton>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path = NormalImage, Convertert={...}"
```

Converter is supposed to check whether NormalImage is null. If so return one kind of text tooltip otherwise another. Let me know if it works.